# Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from short to short

Tags: java

Problem i'm getting is with getters and setters.

I've created setters and getters for a variable data type short.

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getFavoriteColor() {
    return favoriteColor;
}

public void setFavoriteColor(String favoriteColor) {
    this.favoriteColor = favoriteColor;
}

public long getFavoriteNumber() {
    return favoriteNumber;
}

public void setFavoriteNumber(long favoriteNumber) {
    this.favoriteNumber = favoriteNumber;
}

public short getHeightInCent() {
    return heightInCent;
}


public void setHeightInCent(short heightInCent) {
    this.heightInCent = heightInCent;
}


public short getWeight() {
    return weight;
}


public void setWeight(short weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

private String name;
private int age;
private String favoriteColor;
private long favoriteNumber;
private short heightInCent;
private short weight;
```

Above is the Object class that stores this data. In my main class that i'm calling this data from. Everything is called just fine except for the heightInCent and weight. I'm not doing anything different and was wondering why i'm getting this error? I've looked all over the web and here for similar issues but everything i've found is converting form one data type to another. or something along those line. 
Below is my main class.

```
 public static void main(String args[]){

        PeopleObjects person1 = new PeopleObjects();


        person1.setAge(21);
        person1.setName("James Bloggs");
        person1.setFavoriteColor("Green");
        person1.setFavoriteNumber(3248505);
        person1.setWeight(144);
        person1.setHeightInCent(159);

        System.out.println(person1.getName() + ", " + person1.getAge() + ", " + person1.getHeightInCent() + "cm, " + person1.getWeight() + "lb" );
        System.out.println("Favorite Color: " + person1.getFavoriteColor());
        System.out.println("Favorite number: " + person1.getFavoriteColor());

        person1.speak();

        int death = person1.yearsUntilDeath();
        System.out.println(death);

        int age = person1.getAge();

        System.out.println(age);

        String name = person1.getName();

        System.out.println(name);
```

An answer to fix this would be great! What would be even better is (if you know) an explanation why this happened. Thank you all!

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's the error message?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? It's much easier for us to answer the question if (1) we are given the code for the complete program that we can run to see the problem for ourselves and (2) there isn't any unnecessary code in the program.

Comment: Try to change `person1.setWeight(144);` to `person1.setWeight((short) 144);` and the same for person1.setHeightInCent(159)

Comment: Thank you Eran, your help and atmin helped me understand the issue, why it happened, and how to avoid it! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Generally: don't use shorts or even bytes. Java uses Integers and does not care if e.g. a short is meant. If you really must return a short, you have to cast it before.
Just consider this (and there is no other way):

```
byte[] someByteArray = {
    (byte) 0x01,
    (byte) 0x63
}
```

Comment: Thank you atmin! This helped alot! You and Eran helped me understand what i did wrong and why it was wrong!